# How to search a string in a sheetname?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search a particular string in all sheet names of a workbook using For each loop as follows:

```
 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  Name = ActiveSheet.Name
  Next Sheet
```

But i am not able to get all the sheet names using above code as it gets stuck up only one sheet name.

After getting the sheet name i want to **search a particular string** in the sheet name So it would be great if any one can help me in searching a string in all sheets.

Comment: how do you want to list search results ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sheet.Name Like "*" & strSearch & "*" Then
        Debug.Print "Found! " & sheet.Name
    End If
Next
```

You iterate over all sheets, but you always use `ActiveSheet.Name` in your loop.
To search for a pattern, you can use `Like` with the `*` wildcard.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [InStr](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/instr-function-HA001228857.aspx) function as well... or maybe I didn't get your question correctly.

```
Sub CheckSheets()        
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets           
        If InStr(UCase(oSheet.Name), UCase("Sheet")) Then                
            Debug.Print oSheet.Name                
        End If            
    Next oSheet        
End Sub
```