# Find Sheet Name and get Sheet Index

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a sheet by name and get the index of this sheet. I tried it this way but it isn't working.

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*Consolidated EOY*" Then
        Sheet_Nr = Sheet.Index
    End If
Next
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your error ? Does it find the sheet ?

Comment: No error but the variable "Sheet_Nr" is empty

Comment: if you add MsgBox("Test") in your if statment, does the code show the message box ?

Comment: `Like` is actually case-sensitive. Are you sure your sheet has the exact same substring in it? Otherwise, use `LCase` or some other method to make sure you are not stumbling over something this simple.

Comment: No :-( I used the code from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860212/how-to-search-a-string-in-a-sheetname

Comment: The sheet is named "Consolidated EOY ´20-CO20-21" because of the year can change I have to search for a part of the name.

Comment: Try to `Debug.Print  Sheet.Name` outside the `If` to see what sheets it is finding.

Comment: So if case-sensitivity is not the culprit, then there is no `Sheet` with a name like that in the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` collection. Are you opening a second `Workbook` anywhere?

Comment: Maybe using Exit For solve the problem `Sheet_Nr = Sheet.Index: Exit For`

Comment: @YasserKhalil that couldn't be the problem... either the loop finds 1 coincidence or more, but all sheets will have an Index, so an Index must be returned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change the "ThisWorkbook" to the name of the workbook where the sheets are then it works.

```
For Each Sheet In WB_New.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*Consolidated EOY*" Then
        Sheet_Nr = Sheet.Index
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Good learning exercise! [This answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012757/9663006) a few days ago (mind you there are plenty others out there about debugging with far greater detail) might be useful when you get stuck on these kinds of things. When it *should* work but isn't, it's usually a tiny detail that has been overlooked each time you look at it getting more and more frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

The use of `Like` is obviously too imprecise. Here is a function that doesn't need it.

```
Function SheetIndex(NamePartial As String) As Integer

    Dim Sheet       As Worksheet

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sheet
            If InStr(.Name, NamePartial) Then
                SheetIndex = .Index
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Function
```

Call the function with syntax as shown below. If you know that the name you want starts with the partial name you have I recommend to modify the above code using this line instead of the existing, `If InStr(.Name, NamePartial) = 1 Then`

```
Private Sub TestIndex()
    Debug.Print SheetIndex("Consolidated EOY")
End Sub
```

I point out that the `Sheets` collection isn't identical to the `Worksheets` collection and that the data type you are looking for is a `Worksheet`. As a matter of principle, if you don't know the difference between a Sheet and a Worksheet I would recommend that you stick to the kind you do know. From the apect of logic, why should you waste time searching the bigger `Sheets` collection while all you want is contained in the collection of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: @JvdV You seem to conflate "precise" with "flexible". `Like` is very flexible and therefore naturally less precise. Code must naturally be precise. Therefore the more flexible method is often not the best, as is amply demonstrated by this particular thread.